# Issue with jQuery UI Drag & Drop - Won't allow drop in textarea after typing in it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm creating an interface that allows the user to drag & drop preset responses into a "reply" `<textarea>`. I decided to use jQuery UI.

**The issue:** After typing in the `<textarea>`, the **.droppable()** functionality is broken.

I can click inside the `<textarea>` and then drop text into it, but after typing, I can't drop any text into the `<textarea>`...

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(init);

    // Initialization
    function init(){
        // Draggable
        $(".response").draggable({
            helper : "clone",
            cursor : "move"
        });

        // Droppable
        $(".survey-reply textarea").droppable({
            accept : ".response",
            drop : dropResponse
        });
    }

    // When Dropped
    function dropResponse(event,ui) {

        var draggable = ui.draggable;

        // Get existing text
        var text = $(this).text();

        // If field is empty then just apply the dragged response
        if (text == "") {
            $(this).text(draggable.children(".saved-response").val()).appendTo(this);
        }
        // If not, then add the dragged response to the present text
        else {
            $(this).text(text + ' ' + draggable.children(".saved-response").val()).appendTo(this);
        }

    }

});
```

This accomplishes what I need (almost). It allows me to drag the `<li>` responses into a `<textarea>`. It also compiles the text instead of replacing the text in the `<textarea>`.

**What it doesn't do:** I need the user to be able to type in the `<textarea>`, then drag a response into the `<textarea>`, at which time the preset response is added to the typed text.

At the moment, I can click inside the `<textarea>`, and while it is in focus, drag responses into  it. But for some reason, ***typing in the `<textarea>` disables the droppable event...***

***If anyone can help me figure out how to type in the text areas, then drag the responses into the same text area, I would be greatful!***

**Note:** I didn't include the HTML, but I assure you, the selectors are accurate. I do have a **placeholder** attribute applied to the `<textarea>`. I don't believe this has anything to do with the issue (since dragging and dropping the text eliminates the displayed placeholder text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using the `text()` function to get/set the textarea value, what you really want is `val()`.  Also, I don't think you want the `.appendTo(this)` calls where you're updating the textarea value and you don't need to wrap your call to init with `$()`, you can just do `init();`. Change these two lines and it should work:

Change this:

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

to

```
var text = $(this).val();
```

and change this:

```
$(this).text(text + ' ' + draggable.children(".saved-response").val()).appendTo(this);
```

to this:

```
$(this).val(text + ' ' + draggable.children(".saved-response").val());
```

Comment: Thanks man! I tried the .val() on the `var text` earlier, but it was all over I needed to apply that. And the rest of the code I got straight from the jQuery UI Docs... However, my application did not require the .appendTo() either. Thanks very much! @clav

Comment: @derekmx271 : exactly ! helped me today